# Bitcoin Core client on multiple computers

Tags: client, server, connection

I have one computer with a full node bitcoin core. I would like to have bitcoin-qt installed on a different computer but I don't want to download the full blockchain again in the other computer. I would like to have bitcoind active in the first computer and the second one get transaction information from the first one instead of downloading the full blockchain and getting transaction information from a local blockchain copy. Is it possible to do it? And what about my phone getting transaction information from my computer instead of a public blockchain server?

I know I can use the second bitcoin core on pruning mode, but what about not holding any blockchain data locally in the second computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share the blockchain across local network residing on 1 PC, not copy?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/50815/13866)